# AWS-IAM policy on access key giving error message

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, policy

**Policy used :**

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",

    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "iam:*AccessKey*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iam::account#:user/user1"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**What does the policy do :** 
Allows user to change to manage his own access keys .

**What have I tried till now**

1. Attached the above policy to the user
2. Tried logging with the user name and clicked on IAM  and clicked on rotate your access keys and manage your access keys .
3. The error message comes up and doesnt allow the user to change the access keys
4. **Error message is as follows:**

> You need permissions
>   You do not have the permission required to perform this operation. Ask your administrator to add permissions. Learn more
>
> User: arn:aws:iam::account#:user/user1 is not authorized to perform: iam:ListUsers on resource: arn:aws:iam::account#:user/

Comment: The error message suggests that the AWS Management Console also requires users to have the `iam:ListUsers` permission to use the interface. They could rotate keys via the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) without that permission. Also, question mentions policy variables, but your policy doesn't show any variable. I presume you are referring to: [IAM Policy Variables Overview](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_variables.html)

Comment: That's a nice catch, I agree, Initially, when I wrote the policy, I wrote it with a policy variable. I used user/${aws:username} instead of user/user1. Still, no luck then I tried it with a single user and had the same issue.

Answer (score 4):

You need to allow IAM `iam:ListUsers` actions on the `*` resource. The error message indicates missing permission for that action.

See: [Allow a User to List the Account's Groups, Users, Policies, and More for Reporting Purposes](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_delegate-permissions_examples.html#iampolicy-example-userlistall)

There it provides a sample policy to: "Allow Users to Manage Their Own Passwords, Access Keys, and SSH Keys".

The following policy allows users to perform these actions in the AWS Management Console:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "iam:*LoginProfile",
        "iam:*AccessKey*",
        "iam:*SSHPublicKey*"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::account-id-without-hyphens:user/${aws:username}"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "iam:ListAccount*",
        "iam:GetAccountSummary",
        "iam:GetAccountPasswordPolicy",
        "iam:ListUsers"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```